# Images posting from Stack Exchange Android app displaying huge thumbnail in the desktop view

Tags: feature-request, android-app, images, imgur

When posting a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) or [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) with the screenshot/image using the Image uploader from the Stack Exchange Android app, the image is looking fine in the app preview.

But when viewing the same image in the desktop-view, it is occupying the whole screen, the width and height are too high for the image (Huge Thumbnail). So these image's URL is update with `l` (Large Thumbnail) or `m` (Medium Thumbnail) as per the [Imgur image thumbnails guide](https://api.imgur.com/models/image#thumbs) to display normal.

So my [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) is when posting the images from the Android app please reduce the image's width and height than the current size or please update the image URL with the `l` or `m` by default.

---

<sub>Note: Sample posts those are posted from android-app and it's image size are reduced [1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/291718/revisions), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/291556/revisions), [3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/291498/revisions)</sub>