# Detailed info on Imgur's automatic image resizing service?

Tags: support, imgur

I searched for a few posts and they mentioned tweaking image URLs to let Imgur resize images automatically, and here's the info I've known by far.

> 4 available suffices, `lmsh`
>
> `l` is for **large**, forcing down to 640x640
>   `m` is for **medium**
>   `s` is for **small**

Can anyone tell me:

1. What is `h` for?
2. What is the forced resolution for `h`, `m` and `s`?

Comment: This answers your question, though it's not really a dupe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/264393/284336

Comment: @Catjia Thank you for info. That's not complete. See the accepted answer.

Comment: Funilly enough; I had started writing this exact question/answer after [my last experiment with image resizing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298801/351462). Seems like someone beat me to the punch.

Comment: Related: [Thumbnail image on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/74312/162827)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Overall 6 thumbnails are available in Imgur: s, b, t, m, l, h.

Table:

| Thumbnail Suffix | Thumbnail Name | Thumbnail Size | Keeps Image Proportions |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| s | Small Square | 90x90 | No |
| b | Big Square | 160x160 | No |
| t | Small Thumbnail | 160x160 | Yes |
| m | Medium Thumbnail | 320x320 | Yes |
| l | Large Thumbnail | 640x640 | Yes |
| h | Huge Thumbnail | 1024x1024 | Yes |

This can be found at the [Imgur API documentation page](https://api.imgur.com/models/image#thumbs).

Comment: Nice! Is there a list of possible values for the `?s=[x]` appended to the URL to resize it? I always wondered about it. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I didn't find any options like that. I used to know the Imgur API link when I post this [feature-request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291994/312043)

Comment: So maybe it's something tailored especially for SE... back in the day imgur were young and small, so it's possible.