# Do images really have to fill the entire page width?

Tags: support

On [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/384621/underbracing-on-a-set-of-points-in-a-plot-with-pgfplots) on tex.SE (and on many, many other posts on several sites) I once again noticed that pictures uploaded are always made full page width.

This is often way too much for the image. For example in the linked question, I uploaded a math-formatted equation. That would fill the whole width and become enormous. So I have to append white-space on either side of it and upload it like that.

Is there no way to set image sizes? At least to set the sizes to the *original* image sizes - I would understand issues with users setting their own dimensions, but at the very least the picture should not be shown in *larger* dimensions that what it is uploaded in.

Comment: It's becoming enormous because you're *uploading* an enormous image. (The one currently in that post is 1205x520.) We don't ever resize images *up*.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK images can be in any size. Stack Exchange do *not* automatically resize any images if they are not wider than post area width. Oversized images will fit in the post area. Too big images will make your post less readable. You can [manually resize it with Imgur's service](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298822/350567).

An image doesn't necessarily occupy a full line, [image: Humorous] yes.

Comment: Images only occupy a full line if you put them on their own line and format it as a paragraph. It's perfectly possible to have text on the same line as an image. It just looks awful and I wouldn't recommend doing it with any image height that doesn't match the text height.

Comment: @animuson Failed for mobile-web.