# Image on mobile website always occupying full line

Tags: bug, mobile-web, images

[*animuson* suggests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299249/bah#comment972755_299250) that an image can be inserted into texts with proper formatting, and what he said is right when you're on a computer or using SE Android app.

That isn't essentially right when you browse SE with a mobile browser, for example **Google Chrome 59.0.3071.125 on Android 7**.

See screenshot: [image: Screenshot]

Markdown source (my avatar):

```
An image doesn't necessarily occupy a full line, ![Humorous][huaji] yes.
[huaji]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/26fxJ.gif?s=24&g=1
```