# No error message is shown when trying to send a chat message that is too long using the mobile design on Chrome for Android

Tags: bug, chat, user-interface, error-message, mobile-chrome

In the example below, the chat message is too long but clicking on the arrow does nothing. No error message is shown. Tested on Chrome on Android with a Google Pixel 6 with the mobile design.

[image: IMG:]

Note that the error message is shown if using the "Desktop site" option in Chrome:

[image: IMG:]

Comment: Really needed feature for mobile chat. Faced with that issue several times.

Comment: About image sizes, please look at this [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298822/339911). In my edit I left the original image by click, only images in post were reduced, this is the same what you did manually by html.

Comment: Chat has no responsive design. This is the mobile chat, last remnant of the ancient and buggy mobile web.

Comment: Why did my reply to αλεχολυτ get removed?