# Android app bug: A deleted answer shows up on feed

Tags: bug, android-app, android-app-feed

Someone answered my question, about Manjaro on Unix.SE, I reported his answer as "not an answer". The answer was deleted. it still shows in the feed. And when I click on it, my question shows up and an infinite white space.

[image]

[image]

Comment: every time I take a screenshot from the phone it's huge, can't they be resized on SE easily?

Comment: Change the URL of the image so it has an `l` (lowercase L) before the last dot.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog awesome thank you!

Comment: @Lynob Related to your query, already a [feature-request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291994/312043) was posted.

Comment: @Arulkumar thank you sir